# Asp.net mvc core 2.1 response caching not working

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, responsecache

Using visual studio 2017, I created an asp.net core mvc 2.1 application, and added Response Caching.

In Index.cshtml, added

`@DateTime.Now.ToString()`

When I ran the application in a browser, if I reload the page, the output time will vary by each refresh, instead of caching 10000 seconds as specified in the code.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//other code
    services.AddResponseCaching();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
//other code
    app.UseResponseCaching();
}
```

Index action:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 10000, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] {"id"})]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // fetch data from database
}
```

When I inspect the response header:

> cache-control: public,max-age=10000

But still, when refreshing, the output varies each time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: If I use another browser to open the link I can get a cached copy. However if I hit F5 to refresh, I get an updated time.

Second (F5 refreshed) request header:

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: example.com
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98
>   Safari/537.36
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Referer: https://example.com/
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6
>
> Cookie: blablabla

Comment: @mjwills If I hit F5 to refresh, then I get a new time. If I use a new browser tab or another browser, I get a cached copy. I don't understand, the location is set to any which means there should be a cached copy on server, regardless of browser behavior, it should always get same copy in 10000 seconds.

Comment: When you are hitting F5 the browser is likely sending a header to bypass the cache. If you can provide the info requested in my second comment that may be useful.

Comment: @Cal  `If I hit F5 to refresh, then I get a new time`- that's the point. asp.net core response cache store on browser, not in server and that's why you are getting new time always while you are hitting F5.

Comment: Is `app.UseResponseCaching();` above or below `app.UseMvc()`? The reason I ask is because the order matters.

Comment: `asp.net core response cache store on browser, not in server` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2 certainly reads like the caching can be on the server.

Comment: @Benl2 Thank you, I have used Code_Worm's fix in that thread, haven't done thorough testing but it seems to be working.